# How to make two radio buttons required but only one of them should be accepted

Tags: html

I have this:

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" required /> Masculine 
<input type="radio" name="sex" required /> Faminine
```

but if I check one of them, and since both of them are required, I will get alerted that the other one should also be checked. But how do I do so that only one of them must be checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="sex" required /> Masculine <br />
<input type="radio" name="sex" required /> Faminine
</form>
```

Comment: oh if I put in form, then only one of them will be ok?

Answer (score 2):

Your code works as-is on any browser that supports the `required` attribute in the first place. (As far as this attribute is concerned. The code has other problems, like the lack of `value` attributes.)

For a radio button, the [`required` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-required-attribute) is defined in a special way: the “attribute is satisfied if any of the radio buttons in the group is selected”. It would thus be sufficient to use the attribute in one of the radio buttons of the group. However, HTML5 CR adds: “To avoid confusion as to whether a radio button group is required or not, authors are encouraged to specify the attribute on all the radio buttons in a group.” But this just relates to the assumed readability of HTML code, not its functionality.

In this context, HTML5 CR also presents the following remark, which is actually rather unrelated but a good principle: “authors are encouraged to avoid having radio button groups that do not have any initially checked controls in the first place, as this is a state that the user cannot return to, and is therefore generally considered a poor user interface.” If you add a radio button into the group with a meaning like “Does not want to tell” and make it initially checked, the `required` attribute becomes unnecessary. If you wish to force the user into disclosing his or her sex, you would then have to do the check in a different way.